# Apache HttpClient SOAP Request

Tags: java, apache, soap, httpclient

i'm trying to send a request to a webservice. For the requet i'm using this code. The testMessage must be correct, because with SOAPUI the same request is working.

```
            StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(testMessage, "UTF-8");
            stringEntity.setChunked(true);
            String endpointURL = "http://host:8000/wsdl";

            String soapAction = "urn:anyAction";

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(endpointURL);
            httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);
            httpPost.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
            httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type:", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
            httpPost.addHeader("SOAPAction", soapAction);

            String authorization = "user:pass";
            String header = "Basic " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(authorization.getBytes()));

            httpPost.addHeader("Authorization", header);

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

I always getting a fault response:
[soap error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYAgx.png)
I do not understand this message or what should I do... I have the correct wsdl url (it works with SOAPUI).

Thanks for help!

Comment: The error message says not to use the wsdl URL. SoapUI is probably doing that's why its working. If you can just compare the actual message posted by SoapUI and your program, debugging must be easier (try Fiddler). Also why not use libraries so that you don't need to do (and debug) this core task? Spring could be your friend

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My client must be as small and simple as possible. There are only two or three entries i have to commit. So I don't want to use Spring.

Answer (score 1):

I may have had a similar problem in the past...

Like it says in your error message: "To call the Webservice use the service URL instead of the WSDL URL".

Try to open the WSDL URL with your browser. Usually you can find the SERVICE URL at the bottom of the displayed information. Use this URL as your "endpointURL".

Hope I got it right and could help you :)

Comment: Thanks für reply. i figured it out. It was the a false endpoint url. It was also wrong in the WSDL URL as the SERVICE URL. It works now. Thanks so much!